# conditionally replacing number with word

Tags: linux, shell, terminal

I am using a Python script to detect connected devices in my local network every 2 minutes - saving the output in a file (I just save the last number of the ip).

This is my code:

```
import os
os.system('for ip in $(seq 1 10); do ping -c 1 192.168.1.$ip>/dev/null; '
          '[ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "$ip" || : ; '
          'done > /home/pi/Desktop/Network/logs/logLocal.txt')
```

The output ist for example:

```
1
2
4
7
```

My question now is if it is possible to replace the number 7 through a word?
That if device 7 is found the programm writes "seven" not 7 in the file.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: first off use subprocess,  what numbers can potentially be output?

Comment: Have you tried piping the results to `replace "7" "seven"` before redirecting to the output file?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham numbers 1 to 10 could be the output
To Tiger: Can you please send me a link where I can learn this "piping"? I am totally new to this!

Comment: you can redirect the output to a file using subprocess or actually do all but the ping in python and use a dict to map numbers to words. Are you basically pinging and returning the last digit of the ip's that are up?

Comment: Yes Sir - for example my smartphone got the ip 192.168.1.7 - later it just saves the number - but I want to save for number 7 a word - but it could happen that device 7 is not connected - then nothing should happen - sorry for bad English!

Comment: ok I will add an answer using subprocess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following script will do the job:

```
# Note that you can use `{a..b}` instead of `seq`
for ip in {1..10} ; do
   # No need to execute the command and then check it's
   # return value. You can do it in one line
   if ping -c 1 192.168.1.$ip > /dev/null ; then
      # check for `7`
      if [ "$ip" = "7" ] ; then
          echo "seven"
      else if [ "$ip" = 5 ] ; then
          echo "five"

      # ... and so on

      else
          echo "$ip"
      fi
   fi
done > output.txt
```

Comment: Thank you sir - can I add additional a rule for ip = 5, and 4 and so on?

Answer (score 1):

`check_call` will raise a `CalledProcessError` if the ping was unsuccessful so we can catch that exception and do nothing, if the ping was successful we write the value from the dict using the last digit of the  `ip` as the key.

```
from subprocess import check_call, CalledProcessError
from os import devnull


to_words = {1: 'one\n', 2: 'two\n', 3: 'three\n', 4: 'four\n', 5: 'five\n', 6: 'six\n', 7: 'seven\n', 8: 'eight\n', 9: 'nine\n',10:"ten\n"}


with open('/home/pi/Desktop/Network/logs/logLocal.txt', "w") as f:
    for ip in range(1, 11):
        try:
            check_call(["ping", "-c", "1", "192.168.1.{}".format(ip)], stdout=open(devnull, "w"))
            f.write(to_words[ip])
        except CalledProcessError:
            pass
#
```

Comment: No worries, if you have more ip's just increase the range and add more key/value pairings, it is much tidier than having multiple if's

Comment: @piguy Probably you should consider to use this solution since it requires only the necessary operation to be written in bash and the logic remains in python.

Comment: Okay thank you - anyway all this examples here work fine! I am going to use this now!

Answer (score 1):

I would do this a following:

- store all "number word" pairs in a file as `num   name`
- read the file
- ping the number
- echo name if successful

Script:

```
devices="./dev"
while read -r num name
do
    ping -c 1 -t1 192.168.1.$num >/dev/null 2>&1  && echo "$name up"
done < "$devices"
```

btw, with a little modification, you can use `/etc/hosts` directly ;)

also using `nmap` or `fping` or `arp` could be faster as ping each ip in sequence...

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a Unix command in `os.system()`. So you can just pipe the results to `replace` on their way to the file:

```
import os
os.system('for ip in $(seq 1 10); do ping -c 1 192.168.1.$ip>/dev/null; '
      '[ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "$ip" || : ; '
      'done | replace 7 seven > /home/pi/Desktop/Network/logs/logLocal.txt')
```

See [here](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/replace.htm) for more on `replace`.